# This is the sample excel sheet, i need to download ot dynamically from databse. With multirow and multi column in codeignoter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq6b3.png)

This is the sample excel sheet, i need to download ot dynamically from databse.

Comment: You can use this PhpSpreadsheet im using it in some of my projects it is very to use.

Comment: Share it please.How to use it.

Comment: You can see documentation here: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and all the sample codes.  for editing the template you can follow this instruction : https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/